# How to pass arguments to superclass fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I know with Fragments we cannot use its constructor because the system needs the empty one. So to pass data we need to use a static method and bundles like

```
public static A newInstance(int myInt){
    A myA = new A();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("myInt", someInt);
    myA.setArguments(args);

    return myA;
}
```

Okay so far so good.

But what if I want to generify this?

```
public abstract class C{
    private int myInt;

    //Here I cannot use the newInstance because I cannot create an instance of an abstract class
}
```

The outcome should be that I have constructs like this

```
public class A extends C{
   //Some stuff that needs myInt which is stored in superclass because every subclass fragment needs it
}

public class B extends C{
   //Some completly other stuff that also needs myInt
}
```

Both A and B need `myInt` so I would like to have a newInstance method provided by the superclass that I can call and the outcome should be a instance of A or B. How to do this/Is this possible?

Comment: Surely A and B can just access `myInt`? I'm not sure what your issue is?

Comment: "I know with Fragments we cannot use its constructor because the system needs the empty one" - actually you can use `FragmentFactory` https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentFactory

Comment: I will look at this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `C` you can store the instance variable `myInt`, and then override `onCreate()` and in that extract the `myInt` value from the arguments bundle.

When creating a new `A` (`A.getInstance(...)`), you need to put the `myInt` value in the argument bundle. You need to do the same thing when creating a new `B`. To avoid copy-pasting code, you can add a helper method in `C` called (for example) `createArgumentsBundle(myInt)`, that creates a new bundle with `myInt` in it and then send back the bundle.

Comment: I think this is what I want:) Somehow...I don't want to have a lot of redundant code and thinks should kindof work automagically. When I subclass C in a few month it would be nice that there would be an abstract method to override which tells me that I need to pass the argument...otherwise I will forget what I did there :D. I will try the solution

Comment: I mark this as correct as I think this is a solution I can live with. Bundle is supplied by the backend, so I only have to attach it. This sounds about okay. The only thing is, that now I HAVE TO remember that I need to call the superclass getBundle methods. Otherwise the app crashes...but I thinks that's fine

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory to have a static method in fragment class to create it's instance. You can create it from outside as well. A Parent class usually is not supposed to know about its child classes.

Retrieve the Bundle arguments from the base class `C` and set `myInt` there.

`A` and `B`  will get the access. Make sure `myInt` has a  `protected` access modifier.